# AWS crontab not working on Amazon Linux 2/3.0.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I have a laravel project setup on AWS elastic beanstalk(Amazon Linux 2/3.0.1) and I'm trying to setup a cronjob to run a command.
I ran `nano crontab -e` and wrote 
`* * * * * cd /var/app/current && php artisan command:initcrawl` to run for every minute as a test, but it doesn't work.
When i cd in /var/app/current and then run the command manually `php artisan command:initcrawl` it works without any problem.

Comment: Update: I've ran crontab -l to see if it's save properly, but i get "no crontab for ec2-user", even though when i run crontab -e again after saving the line i wrote before is still there.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the fact that I wrote 'nano' in front of the crontab command.
Instead of writing 'nano' in front of the command to use the nano editor i should have done this `export EDITOR='/usr/bin/nano'` then when i run `crontab -e` everything would work fine now.